# Leaflet map in native android apk with cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, leaflet

I am deploying an android app using apache cordova, in the Chrome android browser it works perflectly but in the native apk it shows a white blank page instead the map, it does not render the map properly.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I could solved it of this way, I had a 100 hv for the height of the container-map in the css, when I deployed the apk using cordova (Ionic), the device doesn't interpret this, instead it should set a fixed height according the media queries for each mobile screen for example.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container-map {
    height: 1024px;
  }

}
@media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait){
  .container-map {
    height: 1024px;
  }
}

/**
 * iPad with landscape orientation.
 */
@media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape){
  .container-map {
    height: 768px;
  }
}
```